# Why is gradient used in Fisher Vectors?

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, fisher-information

My understanding of Fisher vectors can be described in the following manner:

A GMM is trained on all data, which gives $p(X,\theta)$, then, for each image/video ($X_i$), the gradient of $p(X,\theta)$ is computed w.r.t $\theta$, evaluated at $X_i$. This shows how the GMM should be altered to fit $X_i$.

I believe this gradient can be considered as the difference between the general distribution and a specific image's distribution.

So my question is:

1. Why is this gradient used at first place? Does it approximate the difference as I guess?
2. Why don't we use an additional EM step on the GMM, this time only with the specific image, to approximate this difference?

Edit: The Fisher vector for classifying images/videos works as follows:
1. Some descriptors are extracted from each image.
2. All descriptors from all images are used to train a GMM.
3. for each image/video ($X_i$), the gradient of log $p(X,\theta)$ is computed w.r.t $\theta$, evaluated at $X_i$. Note that log $p(X,\theta)$ is the sum of logs of different descriptors' likelihoods.
4. This vector of gradients is used as a feature vector for the video. There are as many features as are parameters in GMM.

Comment: Can you provide some context? Is this coming from a paper?

Comment: Improving the Fisher Kernel for Large-Scale Image Classification (Perronnin  et al.)

Comment: Note that there is no "intrinsic" association of Gaussian mixtures and Fisher vectors as far as I know (e.g. no mention [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model)). So I think you need to give more context in your question. At the least, include a citation & [link](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=1671854373527081315) for that paper. However most people here will not want to read through the entire paper just to try and understand your question. So you should highlight the necessary context.

Comment: The most relevant papers to this post are "Improving the Fisher Kernel for Large-Scale Image Classification" (Perronnin  et al.) and "Image Classification with the Fisher Vector: Theory and Practice" (Sanchez et al.)